# VeraCode - This call to name() contains a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw

Tags: javascript, security, xss, veracode

Could anyone explain why VeraCode appears to think using `name` as a public property is a bad idea and propose a good comment for mitigation?

the code (JavaScript):

```
var BatchTask = (function () {
    function BatchTask(batchOrTask, isBatch) {    
        if (isBatch) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            var task = batchOrTask;
            this.name = task.name; // flaw identified on this line
        }
    }
    return BatchTask;
}());
```

the flaw: [CWE-80: Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/80.html)

> **Attack Vector**: name
>
> **Description**: This call to name() contains a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw. The application populates the HTTP response with untrusted
> input, allowing an attacker to embed malicious content, such as
> Javascript code, which will be executed in the context of the victim's
> browser. XSS vulnerabilities are commonly exploited to steal or
> manipulate cookies, modify presentation of content, and compromise
> confidential information, with new attack vectors being discovered on
> a regular basis.

Comment: did you Escape the incoming data (task.name)?

Comment: after a consultation with Veracode people they have confirmed this is a false-negative and is a bug in their engine they will look into.

Comment: please create an answer for that, accept that own answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a consultation with Veracode, they have confirmed this is a false-negative and is a bug in their engine they will look into.